# Homebrew Vim with Python support depends on Python 3.7.0, and I have to use 3.6.5

Tags: homebrew, python, vi

I have to use Python `3.6.5` because of a library I use that keeps showing bugs on `3.7.0` (TensorFlow).

I installed Python `3.6.5` using Homebrew as follows:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

If I install `vim` using Homebrew:

```
brew install vim --with-python
```

it updates Python to `3.7.0`. So I end up having a working vim but broken TensorFlow code. What I did was switching back to `3.6.5` after installing `vim`:

```
brew switch python 3.6.5_1
```

And I ended up having a working TensorFlow code but a broken `vim`:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
[1]    83442 abort      vim
```

Comment: This sounds like a situation begging for a virtual environment. There are a few options for python, but my favorite is [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I'd recommend letting Homebrew manage the 3.7.0 installation and `vim`, and use `pyenv` to manage your development environment with TensorFlow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this with `homebrew`, you can temporarily backdate `homebrew-core` and set the `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE` variable to hold it in place:

```
cd `brew --repo homebrew/core`
git checkout f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
brew install python
brew install vim --with-python
```

I don't recommend permanently backdating homebrew-core, as you will miss out on security patches, but it is useful for testing purposes.

A more robust approach, would be to use `pyenv` as suggested in the comment by @Dustin Wheeler. You can also extract old versions of homebrew formulae into your own tap (tap_owner/tap_name) using the `brew extract` command:

```
brew extract python tap_owner/tap_name --version=3.6.5
```

Comment: `pyenv` worked perfectly and it has a bunch of other lovable features.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, if you also have python 3.7 in your system.
Go to the dir, where vim trying to find the python.

```
cd /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

And create a link to 3.7 python. Example for brew installed python:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/ 3.7
```

Answer (score 2):

Error message:

```
✗ vim test
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
[1]    72498 abort      vim test
```

This upgrade solved my problem:

> brew upgrade vim

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Comment: This worked for me and should probably be the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

For python versioning you shopuld use virtual environments. In these each project can have a different version of python and libraries.

These allow vim to use one version of Python and your Tensorflow project another

There are two of these.

1. [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)
2. Python's inbuilt one [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) recommended since python 3.5